# nvarchar unicode accessing via php pdo odbc display empty

Tags: php, sql, nvarchar, unixodbc

I'm support my project multi language in yii framework. In SQL Server the translated column datatype is nvarchar(max). If i select the translated message it shows empty in php pdo connecting via pdo odbc.

The query i'm using

```
SELECT translation COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as messagedata FROM translated_message
```

Inside foreach i'm using to display the unicode characters iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8', $message);

But it will display junk characters. How can i display it the unicode characters.

Thanks..

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=20.10.1.135;Database=portal

Comment: AFAIK, PHP only calls the ANSI entry point via ODBC, so set your driver to return UTF8 if it doesn't anyway. Not sure what setting the MS driver needs to do that.